# Is it possible to use node.js require() function inside a thread spawned by threads_a_gogo module?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, threads-a-gogo

I want to do some complex stuff inside a thread and use threads_a_gogo for that. But require() function is not defined in child threads. Is there any way to initialize these threads to have it? Also it will be good to have built-in 'process' variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is an  [old feature request](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo/issues/22) but its not implemented yet